# How to assign values to multidimensional array with elements consisting of strings and integers

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have an array:

`comb = [['',0],['',0],['',0],['',0],['',0],['',0],['',0],['',0],['',0],['',0]];`

That is ready to be populated with data, like so:

```
for i = 1:10
    comb(i) = [temp_gen(i, 1:end),temp_fitness(i)];
end
```

Where `temp_gen` is an array of strings and `temp_fitness` is an array of integers, but it gives me the following error:

```
In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.

Error in work (line 23)
    comb(i) = [temp_gen(i, 1:end),temp_fitness(i)];
```

What is causing this error? Am I able to use two different types in a single element? (I still got the same error when I replaced `temp_gen` with an array of integers.

Alternately, is there a way I can combine or associate corresponding elements in different arrays so that I can sort them both? For example say I have an array of strings and a corresponding array of integers, I want to sort them by the size of the integer.

Say: `string = 'a', 'b', 'c';` and `ints = (1, 2, 3);` How would I associate `'a'` with `1`, etc. so that when I sorted `ints` to be 3, 2, 1 `string` would also change to `c, b, a`

Comment: `Cell arrays` is your answer: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here:

The most literal would be to use a [**cell array**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) as this can collect multiple types so either

```
for i = 1:10
    comb{i} = {temp_gen(i, 1:end),temp_fitness(i)};
end
```

or more likely

```
for i = 1:10
    comb(i,1:2) = {temp_gen(i, 1:end),temp_fitness(i)};
end
```

or else you might be able to avoid your loops using `mat2cell`

```
comb(:,2) = mat2cell(temp_fitness, ones(numel(temp_fitness),1))
comb(:,1) = temp_gen;
```

Another option is to use an array of [**struct**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html)s:

```
for i = 1:10
    comb(i).name = temp_gen(i, 1:end);
    comb(i).number = temp_fitness(i);
end
```

And the third option is to keep them as two separate arrays and just make sure that the elements correspond to one another. Here is an example of how to sort one array keeping the corresponding values in the correct elements in a second (i.e. use the second output of [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html?refresh=true)):

```
[temp_fitness, ind] = sort(temp_fitness);
temp_gen = temp_gen(ind);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great, I'm using the cell array solution. Only one little problem: I get 8 blank cells on each row that shouldn't be there, like so: `'1102021322241542...'    [47]    ' '    ' '    ' '    ' '    ' '    ' '    ' '    ' '` I can work around it, but it's not ideal, do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Sounds like you preallocated `comb` incorrectly. Try (making sure `comb` doesn't exist yet) this before your loop: `comb{numel(temp_fitness),2} = []`

Comment: I cleared my variables and re-ran the code and everything came out perfect, thanks again for you help